# Is there a "cleaner" way to refer to a file with a given extension?

Tags: android, java-io, file-extension

When creating file objects from variable names and extensions it seems kind of clunky to have to do things like this:

```
new File(myPath, myFilename + "." + myExtension);
```

or

```
myFilename += "." + myExtension;
```

Is there a better way to do it without having to remember to manually concatenate the period in there?

I'm doing this on Android, but any solution using native Java, Guava, etc would be equally welcome.

Comment: @RobertHarvey could you explain how combining paths is relevant to adding an extension?

Comment: Path combining is the "right" way to do this.  Among other things, it's generally more platform-independent.  If you're squeamish, however, there's still `+=`